# Password confirmation can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, factory-bot, password-confirmation

Would anybody who has more experience with Rails 4 be able to help me out. I'm currently going through "Rails 4 in Action" and I'm having trouble getting one of the specs from the book to pass (specifically from chapter 7.5: Basic Access control -- Namespaced-based CRUD).
I have a spec that creates a FactoryGirl User with admin privileges and tries to create a new user that has admin privileges.

```
spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Creating Users" do
  let!(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }
  before do
    sign_in_as!(admin)

    visit '/'
    click_link "Admin"
    click_link "Users"
    click_link "New User"
  end

  scenario 'Creating a new user' do
    fill_in "Email", with: "newbie@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "hunter2"
    click_button "Create User"
    expect(page).to have_content("User has been created.")
  end
end
```

When I run this spec, I believe I keep getting a "Password Confirmation can't be Blank error".

```
`$ bin/rspec spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb`

    DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade
    documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from get at
    /home/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171)
    F

    Failures:

  1) Creating Users Creating a new user
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("User has been created.")
       expected there to be text "User has been created." in "Signed in as: username Admin Sign out User has not been created. New User 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Password confirmation can't be blank Email Password Is an admin?"
     # ./spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.82 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb:15 # Creating Users Creating a new user

Randomized with seed 56202
```

Here is the factory that creates it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}example.com" }

  factory :user do
    name "username"
    email { generate(:email) }
    #email "newbie@example.com"
    password "hunter2"
    password_confirmation "hunter2"

    factory :admin_user do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the admin controller:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.order(:email)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "User has been created."
      redirect_to admin_users_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "User has not been created."
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

And here is the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password
end
```

And then lastly here is the admin view form where all this information is filled:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box :admin %>
    <%= f.label :admin, "Is an admin?" %>
  </p>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I've tried creating another field in the form for a password confirmation, and then included a fill_in within the spec, but that didn't do anything. I feel like it has something to do with the model having some sort of restriction, not allowing a user to be created unless there's a password confirmation. But I'm not so sure. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Creating another field is what I was about to suggest. What does the test log say when you hit the #create action? (With the other field, I mean, because you are going to need that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried creating another field in the form for a password confirmation, and then included a fill_in within the spec, but that didn't do anything.

**Put that back in**, then delete the entire `attr_accessible` line in the User model.

Mass-assigned attributes are permitted by default in Rails 4 as part of it's [strong parameters](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/strong-parameters-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) strategy -- you don't have to explicitly whitelist attributes in the model.

If this doesn't work, post an updated view including the new `password_confirmation` form field and spec.

Answer (score 0):

That worked!

```
bin/rspec spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb 
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from get at /home/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171)
.

Finished in 0.44082 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 45288
```

Here's the spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "Creating Users" do
  let!(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }
  before do
    sign_in_as!(admin)

    visit '/'
    click_link "Admin"
    click_link "Users"
    click_link "New User"
  end

#=begin
  scenario 'Creating a new user' do
    fill_in "Email", with: "newbie@example.com"
    fill_in "user[password]", with: "hunter2"
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "hunter2"
    click_button "Create User"
    expect(page).to have_content("User has been created.")
  end
#=end
=begin
  scenario "Creating an admin user" do
    fill_in "Email", with: "admin@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "password"
    check "Is an admin?"
    click_button "Create User"
    expect(page).to have_content("User has not been created")
    within("#users") do
      expect(page).to have_content("admin@example.com (Admin)")
    end
  end
=end
end
```

And here's the view:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box :admin %>
    <%= f.label :admin, "Is an admin?" %>
  </p>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Though when I commented out attr_accessible in the user model, I got an error:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password
end
```

Here's the spec now:

```
bin/rspec spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb 
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from get at /home/sean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171)
F

Failures:

  1) Creating Users Creating a new user
     Failure/Error: click_button "Create User"
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: password, password_confirmation
     # ./app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:11:in `create'
     # ./spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.45317 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/admin/creating_users_spec.rb:15 # Creating Users Creating a new user

Randomized with seed 7339
```

So maybe when I tried to create a password confirmation field the last time, I probably left something out and this time I didn't -- so it worked.

Thanks a ton!